# Video output is not showing in OpenPifPaf

Tags: python, opencv, pose-estimation, openpifpaf

I am trying to detect pose from my Webcamera using OpenPifPaf Library (https://openpifpaf.github.io/tutorial_opencv.html). However I am always getting this error, `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__array_interface__'`

This is what I have tried

```
# importing all the libraries
import openpifpaf
import cv2

VIDEO_LINK = 0 # 0 for webcamera
video = cv2.VideoCapture(VIDEO_LINK)
predictor = openpifpaf.Predictor(checkpoint='shufflenetv2k16')
annotation_painter = openpifpaf.show.AnnotationPainter()

while(True):
    _, frame = video.read()
    predictions, gt_anns, meta = predictor.numpy_image(frame)
    # cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    with openpifpaf.show.Canvas.image(frame) as ax:
        img = annotation_painter.annotations(ax, predictions)
        cv2.imshow('frame2', img)

    # to exit the video live
    if cv2.waitKey(33) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I can get the pose estimate in images but I can't get it using video. Any experts advice would help me.

This is the complete error traceback message:

```
src\openpifpaf\csrc\src\cif_hr.cpp:102: UserInfo: resizing cifhr buffer      
src\openpifpaf\csrc\src\occupancy.cpp:53: UserInfo: resizing occupancy buffer
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/Projects/HumanPoseEstimation/openpifpaf_test_on_video.py", line 2, in <module>
    import openpifpaf
  File "D:\Projects\HumanPoseEstimation\human_pose_estimation_venv\lib\site-packages\openpifpaf\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    plugin.register()
  File "D:\Projects\HumanPoseEstimation\human_pose_estimation_venv\lib\site-packages\openpifpaf\plugin.py", line 31, in register
    module = importlib.import_module(name)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "d:\Projects\HumanPoseEstimation\openpifpaf_test_on_video.py", line 16, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('frame2', img)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.8.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:971: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'
```

Comment: complete traceback required. [mre]. -- are you running this on google colab?

Comment: Hi @ChristophRackwitz, Thanks. This is the whole code. On running it I get this always - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__array_interface__' . I am running it in local environment and not in google colab.

Comment: complete traceback required. not a paraphrasing of the traceback but the literal traceback. in the question. you can [edit] it. -- and you forgot all the error checking that is required when using VideoCapture. discard all learning material that fails to show this. since the documentation of this "pifpaf" thing fails to do this, I've opened an issue on their github. https://github.com/openpifpaf/openpifpaf/issues/614

Comment: Hi @ChristophRackwitz, Thank you. I added the traceback here

Comment: now that's a different error and an easily resolvable one. `img` is None or whatever manner of "empty" a numpy array can be. that happens here: `_, frame = video.read()` and it happens for many reasons BUT you still need to add the error checking I talked about before.